# Binding usercontrol inside itemcontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 2 tasks.

1. Add a single usercontrol to a parent window.
2. Add a collection of a usercontrol to a parent window.

I have problem to fulfill task 2 in relation to the data binding and command binding.

if someone knows how to do task 2, please add some code.
This is my implementation for both tasks, in case someone want to fix it.. :

I have a usercontrol called "Book" that contains 3 textblocks and a button.
The userControl has dependecyProperty of my book model and for the button command.

Book.xaml

```
 <UserControl x:Name="MyBookControl"
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  
    AncestorType={x:Type Controls:BookControl}}, Path=TheBook}">
   <Label Grid.Row="0">Title</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Author</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Description</Label>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
     <Button Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding 
    SomeCommand,ElementName=MyBookControl}" Content="Save" />
    </Grid>
```

Book.xaml.cs

```
public partial class BookControl : UserControl
    {
        public BookControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public BookModel TheBook
        {
            get { return (BookModel)GetValue(TheBookProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TheBookProperty, value); }
        }
        public static DependencyProperty TheBookProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TheBook", typeof(BookModel), typeof(BookControl));

        public ICommand SomeCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SomeCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SomeCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SomeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BookControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

BookModel.cs

```
 public class BookModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

In order to complete task 1 I created a window:
BookWindow

```
<Window
       DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
>
<StackPanel>
<Controls:BookControl TheBook="{Binding Book}" SomeCommand="{Binding 
    SaveCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

BookViewModel.cs

```
    public BookModel Book { get; set; }
 public MainViewModel()
        {
            Book = new BookModel{Title = "A Book", Author = "Some Author",   
            Description = "Its a really good book!"};
        }

     private ActionCommand _SaveCommand;
            public ICommand SaveCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_SaveCommand == null)
                    {
                        _SaveCommand = new ActionCommand(OnSaveCommand, CanSaveCommand);
                    }
                    return _SaveCommand;
                }
            }
            protected virtual void OnSaveCommand()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("save clicked");
            }

            protected virtual bool CanSaveCommand()
            {
                return true;
            }
```

Great, Task 1 Completed
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3A8F69A0FB413FA4!116&authkey=!AHiyrfEnBr2a-rM&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Now,  trying to complete task 2:

ContainerWindow:

```
<Window 
  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Container}"
        >
  <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Controls:BookControl  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

ContainerViewModel.cs :

```
  private ObservableCollection<BookModel> books;
        public ObservableCollection<BookModel> Books
        {
            get
            {
                if (books == null)
                {
                    // Not yet created.
                    // Create it.
                    books = new ObservableCollection<BookModel>();
                }

                return books;
            }
        }

        public ContainerViewModel()
        {
            BookModel book1 = new BookModel { Title = "A Book 2", Author = "Some Author", Description = "Its a really good book!" };
            BookModel book2 = new BookModel { Title = "A Book 3", Author = "Some Author", Description = "Its a really good book!" };
            Books.Add(book1);
            Books.Add(book2);
        }
```

The Binding fail, the button "save" stops respoding.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3A8F69A0FB413FA4!121&authkey=!AKnyQk6Ge_9QHug&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

So, what is going on ? why binding fail, why the button "save" is not functioning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting your DependencyProperties in the list example.

```
<DataTemplate>
        <Controls:BookControl  />
</DataTemplate>
```

Look at how you did it in your non-list version.

```
<Controls:BookControl TheBook="{Binding Book}" SomeCommand="{Binding 
SaveCommand}" />
```

That being said, you don't need the DependencyProperties at all, the UserControl will inherit the DataContext for each 'Book' in the list of books as the ItemsControl creates them. You just need to not set the DataContext on the grid.

Then your button could just bind to the BookViewModel command property.

```
<Button Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save" />
```

If your concern is not knowing what is available for the inherited DataContext, you could do this to get design time support.

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:BookViewModel,
                                          IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

Just make sure that the following is defined somewhere in the file, it usually is by default.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

**Update**

So I missed the second issue, should have actually fired up Visual Studio. The issue is that your command is in the MainViewModel.cs. That said, our UserControl has inherited the DataContext of each Book object. The short of it is that the button is looking for the command inside of the Book object.

I'm going to assume that since you have a save command that you will be editing the Book object. So let's take this chance to go ahead and make a ViewModel. I'm going to move the save command to there, so that save is always available off of a BookViewModel. There could be good reasons to have the save command somewhere else, but for simplicity's sake, we'll put it in the ViewModel.

Also, I'm not sure if you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented anywhere, as your MainViewModel and ContainerViewModel don't show that one is used. If you don't, I'd highly recommend you take a step back and look into an implementation or an MVVM framework for your ViewModels.

BookViewModel.cs

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    private readonly BookModel book;

    public BookViewModel(BookModel book)
    {
        this.book = book;
        SaveCommand = new ActionCommand(OnSaveCommand, CanSaveCommand);
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return book.Title; }
        set { book.Title = value; }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get { return book.Author; }
        set { book.Author = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return book.Description; }
        set { book.Description = value; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSaveCommand()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Save clicked for the book '" + Title + "'.");
    }

    protected virtual bool CanSaveCommand()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

That is a very basic example of what you would probably want to do. I wanted to keep it simple to not take away from the example, you will probably want to at least do some null checking.

With the above, you shouldn't have to change your UserControl any, I had to add the row and column definitions, but I ended up with the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Title</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Author</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Author}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Description</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Description}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Content="Save" />
</Grid>
```

Hopefully you noticed that our BookViewModel's constructor accepts a book, so that means that we need to change our ContainerViewModel to house the proper collection and create them correctly.

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<BookViewModel> books;

    public ContainerViewModel()
    {
        Books.Add(
            new BookViewModel(new BookModel
            {
                Title = "A Book 2",
                Author = "Some Author",
                Description = "Its a really good book!"
            }));
        Books.Add(
            new BookViewModel(new BookModel
            {
                Title = "A Book 3",
                Author = "Some Author",
                Description = "Its a really good book!"
            }));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BookViewModel> Books
    {
        get
        {
            if (books == null)
            {
                // Not yet created.
                // Create it.
                books = new ObservableCollection<BookViewModel>();
            }

            return books;
        }
    }
}
```

All that and your ItemsControl can simply be as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Books}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyBookControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.
I did as you suggested (removed the dependency properties from the Book UserControl, assign the command inside the button to point the bookviewmodel). the data binds as expected in both tasks metntioned in my question, however in the list version - the command for each button is not functioning. can you please help with this issue ?

Comment: I see the other issue, I'll provide a solution when I get to a computer. I should have tested what I posted before, my apologies.

Comment: Updated to address the secondary issue. Hope that helps and gets you up and running.

Comment: Hi Richard. Great answer, many thanks. Now I finally understand how to bind the object model and to listen to the click events.I do not know why there some mvvm implementation that holds the collection of the model and not the viewmodel. Interesting how it should be implemented that way, and how should I handle the click command.

Comment: @Liran, It really depends on what you are doing; of course individual opinions may/will vary. There are times when you really don't need a ViewModel, for read-only information I often won't create a ViewModel. I'm sure some purists will hate me for saying that, but that's just my style. For objects that will be edited or need the change notification, then I definitely will create a ViewModel.

Also, if you don't mind, could you please mark the answer as the accepted.